# Proof of $M_{X+Y} = M_XM_Y$ MGF

Tags: integration, jacobian

I'm struggling to complete a proof. In [Moment generating function of $X+Y$ using convolution of $X$ and $Y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868911/moment-generating-function-of-xy-using-convolution-of-x-and-y), the answer gives

$$m_{X+Y}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ts} f_{X+Y}(s) \mathop{ds}= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ts} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(s-y) f_Y(y) \mathop{dy} \mathop{ds}, s = x + y$$

Where $x, y$ are independent. The Jacobian from $(s, y)$ to $(x, y)$ I got $\begin{bmatrix}1 &1 \\ 0 &1\end{bmatrix}$ whose determinant is $1$. I think this means

$$m_{X+Y}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}e^{ty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x) f_Y(y) \mathop{dy} \mathop{dx}$$

So while I can get this to

$$m_{X+Y}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx} f_X(x) \mathop{dx} \cdot \; e^{ty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Y(y) \mathop{dy}$$

I need help getting the $e^{ty}$ inside the integral to complete the proof.

Comment: Why not just move the factor of $e^{ts}$ into the integral with respect to $y$, then change variables?

Comment: @user170231 $s$ and $y$ are not independent so I would need further clarification to move that in

Comment: You can't substituting $e^{ts}$ with $e^{t(x+y)}$ outside the $dy$ integral - $y$ isn't defined outside it. You have to bring $e^{ts}$ inside the inner integral to make the substitution.

Comment: $f(s)\int g(y)\,dy =\int f(s)g(y)\,dy$ always. You don't need "independence" or anything special to do this.

Comment: Indeed, technically, you can't do the substitution without getting it to the double integral form $$\int\int h(y,s)\,dy\,ds.$$

Comment: @user170231 i was spending the last hour to ensure what you said is consistent with what i know, and it is. so thank you

Comment: @ThomasAndrews i was spending the last hour to ensure what you said is consistent with what i know, and it is. so thank you